# Cannot running successful built react-native project on iOS simulator error

Tags: react-native

I'm programming an APP using react-native, but after I pulled from github this morning, it turned out that I couldn't run it anymore. The logs in the command line are as follows：

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
(1 command with analyzer issues)

Logs in "react-native start" command line are as follows:
error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:978:13)
    at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:364:17)
    at BlockScoping.run (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:330:12)
    at PluginPass.BlockStatementSwitchStatementProgram (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:70:24)
    at newFn (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:237:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:65:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:100:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/martin/Desktop/ble-server/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:142:16)
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ../../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.

How could I run it again, it seems that there are no issues with codes.

Answer (score 0):

Please run command first:

`npm start`
and then
`react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

You have probably updated react-native improperly please check the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html).
You may have used

```
npm audit fix
```

which updates react-native.

To fix the problem you can downgrade the react-native version of the app with

```
 npm install react-native@x.x.x"
```

Then re-compile project with

```
react-native run-ios"
```

And don't forget to restart the bundler as well with

```
react-native start
```

Then, if you still want to upgrade the react-native version you can use

```
react-native-git-upgrade
```